# Integrate without using Cosine Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

So I've shown that $\int_{-1}^{1} \sin{\frac{1}{x}} dx$ is integrable using specialized theorems for integrability. My question is if I wanted to compute this integral now is there a way to do so without using the cosine integral $Ci(x)$ after integration by parts. What I mean is that I have so far gotten here:

> $\int_{-1}^{1}\sin{\frac{1}{x}}dx = x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}\Big|_{-1}^{1}+\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos{\frac{1}{x}}}{x} dx$

So is there a way to evaluate the integral $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos{\frac{1}{x}}}{x} dx$ without using $Ci(x)$?

Comment: The integral of the sine function is zero.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see that. Too trivial maybe? lol

Comment: The sine function is an odd function and hence so is $\sin(1/x)$.  The integral exists.  The integration limits are symmetrical around $x=0$.  What is the value of such an integral?  You need not integrate by parts.

Comment: @ Mark Viola Thanks for your response, I saw this already after Andrei's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\;f(x)=\cfrac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x}\;$ is an odd function, it results that $$\int_{-1}^{1}\cfrac{\cos{\frac{1}{x}}}{x} dx=0\;.$$

Comment: Well I guess that is as straightforward as it gets ha ha! I guess the most trivial case often goes above our heads :/